Airflow TriggerDagRunOperator need to wait for multiple executuion of dependent Dag (V2.4.3)
I have a master Dag as below:
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="MASTER_DAG",
    max_active_runs=1,
    schedule_interval="30 4 * * *",
    catchup=False,
    default_args=args,
)

It has below task which triggers DAG_1:
task1 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="task1",
    trigger_dag_id="DAG_1",
    wait_for_completion=True,
    dag=dag,
)

The DAG_1 runs and process some files. If there are more than 1 file, DAG_1 immediately triggers a new instance of DAG_1 but as soon as it completes the first run, the task task1 shows complete.
I need a way to keep the task1 wait until multiple execution of DAG_1 completes.
Tried with wait_for_completion=True, but it just wait for a single execution of DAG_1.
